# List of serial ports

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, tty

I am writing small C project to list available serial ports (actually on Linux). It should list usable ttyS, ttyUSB, pty and so on.
My problem is that I have no idea what is the proper way to do it. For example in my /dev directory I have devices from ttyS0 to ttyS31 but in fact no one is usable. I tried looking for drivers in /sys/class/tty/ttyS* but all devices seems to be real.
Actually I can only list pty's opened by 'socat pty pty', but in my opinion it's hack, because I just wrapped the command 'lsof -w -c socat | grep -o '/dev/pts/[0-9]*' | uniq -u' and I am looking for a better way.

My project: https://github.com/mdrost/serialportlist

I will be grateful for possible technical help and comments about functionality.

Comment: Please add "linux" tag to your question. Thanks.

Comment: You might look into the source code of the `setserial` program for hints. `TIOCGSERIAL` looks useful.